# share multiple image with other apps from react native

Tags: react-native

I try to share multiple photos with other apps(telegram, Instagram,...)in react-native, but I don't know how to share more than one image at on call. any suggestion can be helpful, 
thank you

Comment: I use this lib to share more than one image to other apps [react-native-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share) with converting the images to base64 and send your images as an array to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I use this lib to share more than one image to another apps.[react-native-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share).
This is a simple way to do this on react native.

```
shareImage(images) {
    const shareOptions = {
      title: 'Share file',
          urls:images,
        };
    return Share.open(shareOptions);
};

_renderShareIt(base64Items){
   let selectedImages=[]
   base64Items.map((images)=>{
      // push selected images on an array
   });
   if(selectedImages.length > 0){
        this.shareImage(selectedImages)
     }else{
        // show an alert, no image selected
     }
}
```

hopefully it was useful :)